# Функция map() или списковое включение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, map

Для применения функции к каждому элементу итерируемого объекта в питоне существует два способа:

1. Функция `map()`:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(map(str, lst))
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> list(map(lambda a: a + 1, lst))
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

2. Списковое включение:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [str(i) for i in lst]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> [i + 1 for i in lst]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

В "Дзене Python" есть строчка, которая гласит:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

> Должен существовать один и, желательно, только один очевидный способ сделать это.

Раз существует два способа применения функций к итерируемым объектам, значит, у создателей питона были веские причины для их ввода.

Возникает вопрос: какие? В приведенных выше примерах оба способа выглядят довольно естественно. По всей видимости, существуют задачи, в которых проще использовать только один из этих способов. Так в когда лучше употреблять `map()`, а когда — списковое включение?

Comment: Списковое включение, по-моему, гораздо понятнее с первого взгляда

Comment: Что-то похожие на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1247486/21103781

Comment: @wchistow, если честно, я сам чаще пользуюсь списковыми включениями. Но когда пишешь большой однострочник, то `map(str, lst)` воспринимается гораздо проще своего спискового аналога.

Comment: Да, и видимо из-за этого они оба и существуют - каждый удобен в разных случаях.

Comment: В pylint есть правило [bad-builtin / W0141](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v2.17.5/user_guide/messages/warning/bad-builtin.html) полностью запрещающее использовать `map`

Comment: А вот сравнение на хабре: https://habr.com/ru/articles/479252/

Comment: @andreymal, ничего оно не запрещает, а только предупреждает о БП.

Comment: [Задал](https://discuss.python.org/t/the-map-function-or-the-list-comprehension/33613) этот вопрос на [Discussions on Python.org](https://discuss.python.org/), посмотрим, что скажут...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Перевод с английского [ответа](https://discuss.python.org/t/the-map-function-or-the-list-comprehension/33613/5) на [Discussions on Python.org](https://discuss.python.org/)*

---

Было бы неплохо, если бы существовал только один "очевидный способ сделать это", но это почти никогда невозможно. Разным людям разные вещи покажутся очевидными. Это правило предназначено скорее для разработчиков языков, чем для программистов: когда есть общая задача, требующая нескольких строк кода, и люди пишут код по-разному, и каждый способ требует немного обдумывания... тогда хорошо-бы сделать так, чтобы язык предоставлял более явную поддержку. Даже если все делают это одинаково, это не должно казаться слишком абстрактным. Следуя этому принципу, мы получаем приятные удобства, такие как `random.choice`.

Что касается сравнения `map` со списковым включением, то вот мое (*Karl Knechtel*) личное руководство:

Обычно предпочтительнее использование спискового включения.

Используйте `map`, когда:

- функция, которую вы хотите применить, уже существует (особенно если она встроенная):

  ```py
  >>> # можно и так
  >>> [str(x) for x in range(10)]
  ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
  >>> # способ с map короче, что может быть преимуществом
  >>> list(map(str, range(10)))
  ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
  ```
- вы можете легко написать преобразование через функцию, *при том, что* эта функция принимает несколько аргументов из параллельных списков:

  ```py
  >>> [x*y for x, y in zip(range(10), range(10, 20))]
  [0, 11, 24, 39, 56, 75, 96, 119, 144, 171]
  >>> # в map уже встроена zip
  >>> list(map(lambda x, y: x*y, range(10), range(10, 20)))
  [0, 11, 24, 39, 56, 75, 96, 119, 144, 171]
  ```

Особенно хорошо списковое включение, когда вам также нужна фильтрация:

```py
>>> list(map(lambda x: x + 1, filter(lambda x: x % 3, range(10))))
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
>>> # гораздо проще
>>> [x + 1 for x in range(10) if x % 3]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

В Python3 `map` является "ленивым". Если вам нужен этот отложенный результат, но вы хотите использовать синтаксис спискового включения, напишите вместо него выражение генератора:

```py
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> (x for x in range(10)) # В результате получается не кортеж
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1ddd439120>
```

Полученный объект-генератор можно использовать всеми теми же основными способами, что и результат отображения. (Есть технические различия, но здесь они не важны.)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо. С английским у вас все нормально, перевод отличный)

Answer (score 1):

Генераторы (то что называют кратким итератором) могут использовать условия стрима. В то время как `map` независим от внешних условий. Если нужно просто применить функцию (да хоть лямбду) к каждому элементу - используйте `map`. Возвращаемый объект можно проитерировать, и преобразовать в `list` (как в вашем коде). В то время как генераторы больше подходят, когда нужно сгенерировать и продолжить дальше с ним работу итерируемый объект, можно с условием, можно просто заполненный.

**UPD** | Примеры кода где показана разница между `map` и генератором:

Через функцию `map`:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = list(map(lambda x: x * 2, numbers))
print(result)  # Output: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Через генератор:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = [x * 2 for x in numbers]
print(result)  # Output: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Если говорить проще - генератор лучше использовать, когда нужно произвести операцию с/над объектом (методы, арифметические операции) или , а `map`, когда объекты нужно преобразовать, то есть технически сам объект преобразования не сохраняется.

Comment: Можно объединить map с filter

Comment: Речь вроде бы не о генераторах, а о списковых включениях...

Comment: @wchistow, по сути это одно и тоже. Просто генератор можно преобразовать в СВ, а мап выкидывает итерируемый объект и всё.

Comment: У вас там опечатка. Не UDP, а UPD)

Comment: Если под термином *генератор* вы подразумеваете английское *generator*, почитайте вот это: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19.

Comment: Под генератором я подразумеваю краткий `for`, который возвращает всегда `generator object`